# Django refuses to use DB view

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I have the following scenario:

- I have defined the right view in the database, taking care that the view is named according to the django conventions
- I have made sure that my model is not managed by `django`. The migration created is accordingly defined with `managed=False`
- The DB view is working fine by itself.

When triggering the API endpoint, two strange things happen:

1. the request to the database fails with:

   ERROR:  relation "consumption_recentconsumption" does not exist at character 673

(I have logging enabled at the `postgres` level, and copy-pasting the exact same request into a db console client works, **without modifications whatsoever**)

2. the request to the DB gets retried lots of times (more than 30?). Why is this happening? Is there a `django` setting to control this? (I am sending the request to the API just once, manually with `curl`)

### EDIT

This is my model:

```
class RecentConsumption(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

This is the `SQL` statement, as generated by `django` and sent to the db:

```
SELECT "consumption_recentconsumption"."id", "consumption_recentconsumption"."name", ... FROM "consumption_recentconsumption" LIMIT 21;
```

As I mentioned, this fails through `django`, but works fine when run directly against the db.

### EDIT2

Logs from postgres, when running the sql directly:

```
2018-12-13 11:12:02.954 UTC [66] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SAVEPOINT JDBC_SAVEPOINT_4
2018-12-13 11:12:02.955 UTC [66] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: SELECT "consumption_recentconsumption"."id", "consumption_recentconsumption"."name", "consumption_recentconsumption"."date", "consumption_recentconsumption"."psc", "consumption_recentconsumption"."material", "consumption_recentconsumption"."system", "consumption_recentconsumption"."env", "consumption_recentconsumption"."objs", "consumption_recentconsumption"."size", "consumption_recentconsumption"."used", "consumption_recentconsumption"."location", "consumption_recentconsumption"."WWN", "consumption_recentconsumption"."hosts", "consumption_recentconsumption"."pool_name", "consumption_recentconsumption"."storage_name", "consumption_recentconsumption"."server" FROM "consumption_recentconsumption" LIMIT 21
2018-12-13 11:12:10.038 UTC [66] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: RELEASE SAVEPOINT JDBC_SAVEPOINT_4
```

Logs from postgres when running through django (repeated more than 30 times):

```
2018-12-13 11:13:50.782 UTC [75] LOG:  statement: SELECT "consumption_recentconsumption"."id", "consumption_recentconsumption"."name", "consumption_recentconsumption"."date", "consumption_recentconsumption"."psc", "consumption_recentconsumption"."material", "consumption_recentconsumption"."system", "consumption_recentconsumption"."env", "consumption_recentconsumption"."objs", "consumption_recentconsumption"."size", "consumption_recentconsumption"."used", "consumption_recentconsumption"."location", "consumption_recentconsumption"."WWN", "consumption_recentconsumption"."hosts", "consumption_recentconsumption"."pool_name", "consumption_recentconsumption"."storage_name", "consumption_recentconsumption"."server" FROM "consumption_recentconsumption" LIMIT 21
2018-12-13 11:13:50.783 UTC [75] ERROR:  relation "consumption_recentconsumption" does not exist at character 673
2018-12-13 11:13:50.783 UTC [75] STATEMENT:  SELECT "consumption_recentconsumption"."id", "consumption_recentconsumption"."name", "consumption_recentconsumption"."date", "consumption_recentconsumption"."psc", "consumption_recentconsumption"."material", "consumption_recentconsumption"."system", "consumption_recentconsumption"."env", "consumption_recentconsumption"."objs", "consumption_recentconsumption"."size", "consumption_recentconsumption"."used", "consumption_recentconsumption"."location", "consumption_recentconsumption"."WWN", "consumption_recentconsumption"."hosts", "consumption_recentconsumption"."pool_name", "consumption_recentconsumption"."storage_name", "consumption_recentconsumption"."server" FROM "consumption_recentconsumption" LIMIT 21
```

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing the code of the model and the view. And where are you seeing the db calls?

Comment: @DanielRoseman as I mentioned, in the postgres logs

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself, in case this helps somebody in the future.

I am running the `CREATE VIEW` command in `PyCharm`, which seems to use a transaction for all operations. That means that the view is available within the db session in `PyCharm` (since it uses the transaction for all requests), but not from outside. The `django` app is running in the console, and does not see the view.

The solution is just to commit the transaction in `PyCharm`, to make it fully visible.

The final solution is to create the view via django migrations.